# The state of Workflow Foundation

Tags: workflow-foundation

I have a project coming up soon and I was starting to think about what technologies would be good to use.  There will be a lot of workflow scenarios, and this got me thinking about Workflow Foundation.  I have done a few tutorials in the past and found them very useful, but I was wondering if this is still being developed or whether Microsoft has put it on the back burner?  I'm a bit concerned about using something that won't be around (or is no longer around) in the future for support reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is definitely not on the back burner.  We have a very active team and much work going on.  To keep up check out [my blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/rjacobs) or our podcast show [AppFabric.tv](http://appfabric.tv) or it's predecessor [endpoint.tv](http://channel9.msdn.com/shows/Endpoint/)